# Measure theory questions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, uniform-integrability

i. If $1 < p < \infty$ and $E = \{f_a, a \in A\}$ set of measurable functions of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\sup_{a \in A} ||f_a||_p < \infty$, I want to show that for $ 0 < q < p$, $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \sup \limits_{a \in A} \int_{|f_a| > x} |f_a|^q = 0$.

ii. For bounded Borel $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ where $\int fg = 0$ for all $g \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$, I want to show $ f=0$ a.e.

iii. I want to show that $\forall \epsilon\gt0, \exists \delta\gt0$ s.t. $m(E \subseteq \mathbb{R}) < \delta \Rightarrow \int_E |f_a|^q < \epsilon$

My thoughts were for one to use Hölder's inequality to  use Borel-Cantelli, but that didn't get me anywhere. For two, it seems obviously if $g \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ then set of discontinuities are countable so then $f$ must be zero a.e.

Comment: For i., can you bound the measure of $\{|f_a|\gt x\}$ uniformly on $a$ in $A$?

Comment: Could you try and make your title a little more informative? Measure theory sure is a broad subject.

Answer (score 4):

1. Note that
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \int_{|f_a|\gt x}|f_a(t)|^q\,\mathrm{d}t
   &\le\frac1{x^{p-q}}\int_{|f_a|\gt x}|f_a(t)|^p\,\mathrm{d}t\\
   &\le\frac1{x^{p-q}}\int|f_a(t)|^p\,\mathrm{d}t\\
   &\le\frac1{x^{p-q}}\|f_a\|_p^p\\
   \sup_{a\in A}\int_{|f_a|\gt x}|f_a(t)|^q\,\mathrm{d}t&\le\frac1{x^{p-q}}\left(\sup_{a\in A}\|f_a\|_p\right)^p
   \end{align}
   $$
   Now take the limit as $x\to\infty$.
2. Given $\epsilon>0$ and $a<b\in\mathbb{R}$, find a $g\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ so that $\|f-g\|_{L^2[a,b]}<\epsilon$. Then
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \|f\|_{L^2[a,b]}^2+\|g\|_{L^2[a,b]}^2
   &=\int_a^b\left(f(x)^2+g(x)^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
   &=\int_a^b\left(f(x)-g(x)\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\\
   &\le\epsilon^2
   \end{align}
   $$
   Thus, $\|f\|_{L^2[a,b]}\le\epsilon$ and since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we have
   $$
   \|f\|_{L^2[a,b]}=0
   $$
3. Let
   $$
   E_\lambda=\{x:|f(x)|\gt\lambda\}
   $$
   Then by Dominated Convergence
   $$
   \lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\int_{E_\lambda}|f(x)|^q\,\mathrm{d}x=0
   $$
   There are two possibilities, either there is some $\Lambda$ so that $\lambda\gt\Lambda\Rightarrow m(E_\lambda)=0$, or $\forall\lambda>0,m(E_\lambda)\gt0$. If $\Lambda$ exists, then $\delta\lt\epsilon/\Lambda$ will do since $f$ is essentially bounded. Otherwise, choose a $\lambda_\epsilon$ large enough so that if $\lambda\ge\lambda_\epsilon$,
   $$
   \int_{E_\lambda}|f(x)|^q\,\mathrm{d}x\lt\epsilon
   $$
   Such a $\lambda_\epsilon$ is guaranteed by the previous limit. Choose $\delta=m\left(E_{\large\lambda_\epsilon}\right)\gt0$. Integration over any set of measure $\delta$ will be at most the integral over $E_{\large\lambda_\epsilon}$.

Comment: Your solution in 2. relies on the assumption that $C_c(\Bbb R)$ is dense in $L^2[a,b]$ for all $a$ and $b$. Is it simpler to establish this than a direct approach?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: If we don't assume density, then there is more to do all around. If density is not a given, then perhaps a proof paralleling the proof of density would be shorter than proving density and then using the argument above.

Comment: For 1, I am having trouble seeing why the first line is true:
$\int_{|f_a|>x} |f_a(t)|^q dt \le \frac{1}{x^{p-q}} \int_{|f_a|>x} |f_a(t)|^p dt$

Comment: @chinaschool: Wherever $|f_a|\gt x$, we also have that $|f_a|^{p-q}\gt x^{p-q}$. Thus, $|f_a|^p\frac1{x^{p-q}}\gt|f_a|^q$.

Comment: As a follow up, how would I show that $m(E\subseteq \mathbb{R}) < \delta \Rightarrow \int_E |f_a|^q < \epsilon$

Comment: @chinaschool: do you mean that $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0:\dots$ This is a little long for a comment, and since it is separate from your question, it should be either added to your question, or asked as a separate question.

Comment: Yes and I added to question.

Comment: Why is $E_{\lambda}$ measurable? and do you mean $\forall \lambda >0, m(E_{\lambda}) = 0$

Comment: @chinaschool: $E_\lambda$ is measurable since $f$ is measurable. No, I meant what is there. Either $m(E_\lambda)=0$ at some $\lambda$, or $m(E_\lambda)\ne0$ for all $\lambda$.

Comment: But then how could the integral go to zero if $m(E_{\lambda}) > 0 \forall \lambda$

Comment: @chinaschool: think about $\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: Right... the integral is 2 for that? And I dont quite see how Dominated Convergence theorem applies here (thought it was for functions in $L_1$ as opposed to sets though $E_{n+1} \subset E_n$)

Comment: @chinaschool: The dominating function is $|f|^q\,\mathbf{1}_{E_1}$, which is in $L^1$, and the functions $|f|^q\,\mathbf{1}_{E_\lambda}\to0$ as $\lambda\to\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the first question has been already given. For the second one, 
first approximate pointwise the characteristic function of a compact set by continuous functions with compact support.

As we can choose the sequence monotonic, we can actually show that for each compact $K$,
$$\int f\chi_Kd\lambda=0.$$
By regularity of Lebesgue measure, we can deduce that $\int f\chi_Sd\lambda=0$ for each measurable set $S$ of finite measure. Conclude.